# return signature from Signature Container Class back to a Widget

Tags: flutter, package, widget, signature

I am calling the sketchContainer class from a Widget inside FormService class.
I can't seem to return the signature back to this widget. Stuck for hours.

```
class FormService {
  late String selectedLanguage;

  FormService(this.selectedLanguage);
  // more code


  Widget getSignature(ElementChild element, BuildContext context) {
    SignatureController controller = SignatureController(
      penStrokeWidth: 3,
      penColor: Colors.black,
      exportBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );

    return SketchContainer(controller: controller);
  }
}
```

the sketch container widget looks like this:

```
class SketchContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final SignatureController controller;

  const SketchContainer({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SketchContainerState createState() => _SketchContainerState();
}

class _SketchContainerState extends State<SketchContainer> {
  double containerHeight = 250; // Default height

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    widget.controller.addListener(() {});
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.signature),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.h),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: ThemeProvider.instance.onSurfaceColor.withOpacity(0.1),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onLongPress: () {
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return popUpContainer(SignatureClearPopupWidget(
                                controller: widget.controller));
                          });
                    },
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        widget.controller.undo();
                        // Handle delete button action
                      },
                      icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg_icons/delete.svg'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                  height: containerHeight,
                  child: Signature(
                    controller: widget.controller,
                    height: containerHeight,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  )),
              
              SizedBox(height: 24.h)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have called the class and passed a controller to it.
but how can it constantly listen to changes and save the last drawn one?